# Commerce Server Catalog Manager Error: Failed to get Dependent Catalogs

Tags: sitecore-commerce

We are using *Sitecore Commerce 8.1 powered by Commerce Server* and in the **Commerce server Catalog Manager** we are getting the below error when we select the catalog.:
[image] 
The error from the eventviewer are as below:
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

The Properties are also not showing for the Property definitions but are present in the available properties of Product definitions.
Have anyone faced such kind of error or any clue about the fix needed?
In TDS with Get Sitecore items I am getting the error :"Failed to get the Dependent Catalogs"
[image]

Comment: It is always recommended to post errors/exceptions in a Block Quote or Code sample for the ease of future searches. Please avoid posting screen shots with errors.

Comment: It to me like connection SQL Server from commerce webservices. Are you sure it is properly configured?

Comment: @AmitabhVyas Sure I do understand your point and thanks for the input.

Comment: @PeterProchazka yes it is properly configured and it was working fine but the issue started when executing a Job and after that this is broken. The error I see mainly is as below:                                                                                          INFO  CUpdateJob > Updating of the inventory catalog with information about materials > Started.
ERROR Failed to get the dependent catalogs.
Exception: CommerceServer.Core.Catalog.CatalogDatabaseException
Message: Failed to get the dependent catalogs.
Source: CommerceServer.Core.CatalogServer

Answer (score 1):

I have figured out the cause of the issue and have a fix, rather a work around to get rid of the error and have my Commerce Server up and running for edit.
The issue was the database got corrupted with invalid data. So I did a restore of the Commerce database and after that the error message got removed.